# Why can I not install Firefox on my HTC G1/Dream with CyanogenMod 6.1?

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, htc-dream, firefox-for-android

I have a HTC G1/Dream with CyanogenMod 6.1, based on Android 2.2.1. I would like to install [Firefox](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox), which requires Android 2.0 and up. But I cannot find it in the Android Market, and when I try to install it remotely from the web Android Market, I can see "This article is not compatible with your device".

What could be the origin of my problem?

Comment: What does it say when you try to install?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox also requires an ARMv7 processor. The HTC Dream/G1 is officially unsupported because its processor is ARMv6. See the [supported/unsupported device list](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#System_Requirements) on the Mozilla wiki:

> These devices have ARMv6 processors and are not compatible with
>   Firefox for Android:
>
> ...
>
> - HTC Dream (T-Mobile G1, Android Dev Phone 1)
>
> ...

Answer (score 2):

[The answer to this question from `eldarerathis`](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18565) is currently correct; now, though, ARMv6 support is in the works too, and it can be [downloaded from Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#ARMv6_.28experimental.29).

(However, the Aurora build of mobile Firefox worked better for me than the [nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) build last time I tried it; however, I have a slightly unusual device using a QVGA (small) screen and a keyboard).